Preventing Output of Layout Styles but Keep the Layout Classes in Core Block Editor
I am creating a block theme where the CSS styles for block layout support get included via the theme stylesheet files. To opt out from WP printing all the styles for separate blocks, I set support for disable-layout-styles in my theme.
In the frontend everything works as expected, with the layout styles not beind printed, but I still have the layout classes (.is-*, as described here). In the editor the layout classes don't get added to the blocks anymore. This disables all my styling rules for block layouts.
The Problem can be reproduced by creating a minimal child theme from twentytwentyfour.
style.css:
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-Four Child Test
Template: twentytwentyfour
*/

functions.php:
<?php
add_theme_support( 'disable-layout-styles' );

Then create a new post and add a group block setting the layout to row. In the editor there is no .is-layout-flex on the block element. When looking at the preview in the freontend, the class can be found.
Tested on current WP (6.5.2) with a Child theme of TwentyTwentyFour as described above, no plugins active.
I am looking for a mechanism to re-enable the layout classes for the editor. Diving through the WordPress Developer Resources and also doing Google research did not bring up results helping me in this matter.

Turns out, this is a regression in the block editor of WP 6.5.
The issue has been fixed in the Gutenberg Plugin at version 18.2. Installing the plugin will remedy the problem until the fix lands in WP Core.
